# Multiclassification with hundreds or thousand of classes?

Tags: neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have a problem which requires 100-1000 classes and I'm wondering how to handle it.
Neither traditional classification nor regression seems like a good solution

```
 Here is the scenario in more details :
 - P number of possible classes (100-1000-X000)
 - I number of inputs (every input accept a class)
 - O number of outputs (every output accept a class)
```

F.e. how a datastream may look like for **P=5 => a,b,c,d,e ; I=3; O=3**

```
inputs => outputs
 a,c,d      b,a,a
 d,b,c      c,e,a
 a,a,d      e,d,b
 .....      .....
```

In my case **P=hundreds, I=10ths, O=10ths.**
Every I|O can accept any of P-classes.

As additional complication the inputs and outputs are 2D, but ignore this for now.

How would you handle this scenario ?

What topology the NN has to have ? What kind of loss-fun ? what kind of output-activation ? ....etc

Comment: The ImageNet dataset has 1000 classes and there are many neural networks that are trained on it, so take a look at that first.